# .htaccess rewriting PHP URL to clear .php

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php file witht he following

original
www.mysite.com/Biz/I.php?id=10-variable-page-name

I want to look like

mysite.com/Biz/variable-page-name/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Biz/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ I.php?id=$2-$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: not working so far I beleive variable-page-name can have different string as per page id i.e. for every .php?id=5 page name is different

Comment: I want the file to be in /Biz/ directory not in root directory is that possible?

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.